# What information does $g^x$ reveal about $x$?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, randomness, commitments

Let $p$ be a large prime number. Let $G$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ with order $q$ - again a large prime. Let $g$ be a generator of $G$.

Consider the following standard protocol for generating a random element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_P$:

- Player 1 generates a random number $x_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and outputs $g^{x_1}$ as a binding commitment.
- Player 2 generates a random number $x_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and outputs $g^{x_2}$ as a binding commitment.
- The two players reveal $x_1, x_2$, and after checking consistency with the commitments, the output of the whole process is defined as $x = x_1 +x_2 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$.

Suppose now that Player 2 would like to manipulate $x$. Her strategy is the following: She sees $g^{x_1}$. She generates $n$ random number $a_1, ...,a_n$. She computes $g^{x_1+a_1}, ..., g^{x_1+a_n}$, see which one she likes best, and sets $x_2$ accordingly: $x_2 = a_i$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$. Finally, she outputs a commitment $g^{x_2}$.

This scheme is not considered secure, since Player 2 can obviously affects the distribution of $g^{x_1+x_2}$ and therefore the distribution of $x$.

> My question is, can Player 2 *really* manipulate $x$ to her benefit?

One way to formalise this question would be: Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}_P^*$. If Player 2 is honest, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}[x \in A] = \frac{|A|}{p-1}.
$$
Can Player 2 increase this probability using the above strategy?

(Naturally, $A$ can be defined by "the set of all numbers $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $g^x$ has a '1' in the last digit" and then Player 2 can easily make this probability equal 1, so this formalisation is not very good. Suggestions?)

Comment: It seams to me that you have already answered your own question...

Comment: @fkraiem :) still, if x is the next lottery number, could you manipulate it just by looking at g^x?

Answer (score 2):

You state

> One way to formalise this question would be: Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}_P^*$. If Player 2 is honest, we have
>   $$
> \mathbb{P}[x \in A] = \frac{|A|}{p-1}.
> $$
>   Can Player 2 increase this probability using the above strategy?
>
> (Naturally, $A$ can be defined by "the set of all numbers $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $g^x$ has a '1' in the last digit" and then Player 2 can easily make this probability equal 1, so this formalisation is not very good. Suggestions?)

One way to address this issue, let's call it *the encoding of $A$ issue* is to hide the obvious properties of $A.$ Thus the players can interact with a randomized encoding of $A.$ Specifically, for your case, we can define $A$ as the set of all numbers $x$ in the integers modulo $n$ such that $H(x)$ has a certain bit pattern $(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_t)$ in its leading $t$ bits, where $H$ is a secure hash function.

So the game can be played on the hashed image of the relevant quantities.

Comment: Of all encoding functions, probably the one that the adversary is _not_ going to choose is a hash function, no? what information can an adversary gain from the hashed image of $A$?

Comment: This is how one can *prevent* an adversary from learning $x$. It was unclear in the question that the adversary chose the encoding, not a standard state of affairs.

Comment: I apologise if the question wasn't clear enough, although I can't see why what you describe would be a common practice. Perhaps I'm missing something.